# Differentiate $f(z) = zRe(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What I tried was the following (with $z = x + yi$):

I wrote $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + v(x,y)i$  so in that case, $f(z) = zRe(z) = f(x,y) = x^2 + xyi$.

Then, by using $\nabla u(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  -1 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}\nabla v(x,y)$ I found that the function $f(z)$ is only differentiable at $z=0$.

So I started trying to calculate $f'(0)$ using the product rule: $f'(z) = \frac{d}{dz}(zRe(z)) = Re(z) + z\frac{d}{dz}(Re(z))$ but at that point it's easy to show that it is not possible to calculate $\frac{d}{dz}(Re(z))$ by using the definition of the derivative and seeing that the limit will yield different results for different paths. From here, how can I proceed?

Comment: *Hint:* $Re(z)=(z+\bar z)/2$.

Comment: No need for the product rule for $f'(0)$, $\frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z} = \operatorname{Re} z \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you can compute $f'(0)$ directly from the definition of the derivative.

If you're familiar at all with differentials, it may be illuminating to compute

$$ d(\text{Re}(z)) = d\left( \frac{z + \bar{z}}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{2} ( dz + d\bar{z} )$$

and

$$ d(z \text{Re}(z)) = z d(\text{Re}(z)) + \text{Re}(z) dz = \left(z + \frac{\bar{z}}{2} \right) dz + \frac{\bar{z}}{2} d\bar{z}$$

In general, when expanding $df$ like this, we get $g dz + h d\bar{z}$; $h$ is zero precisely when $f$ is differentiable, and when that happens, the derivative is $g$.